# Using count() or findOne() for better performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using NodeJs and native MongoDB driver for creating an application.
I want to ensure that one record with a specific condition is exists or not and I want to know that which method is better?

```
collection.find({...}).count(function(err, count){
    if(count > 0) {
       //blah blah
    }
})
```

or

```
collection.findOne({...}, function(err, object){
    //blah blah
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls). I believe `find` with `limit(1)` is way to go in your case. (If you want to get actual document data with query, then use `findOne`).

In terms of `mongodb-native`, code will look something like this

```js
function recordExists(selector, callback) {
  collection.find(selector, {limit: 1}, function(err, cursor) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    cursor.count(function(err, cnt) {
      return callback(err, !!cnt);
    });
  });
}
```

---

I am little confused about this: `collection.find({...}).count`. Is native driver allows to do that? Is it `cursor.count`? Anyway, `limit` is your friend here.

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. But actually I don't want to get the document...I want only ensure that this row is exists. So still you recommend using `limit`?

Comment: @Afshin, yeah, find with limit.

Comment: I use your code but in `count` callback, the `cnt` is 3 for me but I set `limit` to 1...

Comment: Honestly if you are just interested that the document exists just use `findOne()`. Will return an single document which match the criteria, instead of a cursor limited by one result.

Comment: @Afshin, my bad, second argument in `collection.find` is fields, you want to get. Options for query is third parameter, so the second line should be: `collection.find(selector, {}, {limit: 1}...`.